# Plot sin(x)/x using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Something is going wrong here...

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
    \resizebox{.5\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\begin{axis}[grid=both,xmin=-4,xmax=4,ymin=-2,ymax=2,xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,axis lines=center,>=stealth]
\addplot[domain=-4:4, blue, ultra thick] plot[smooth] {sin(deg(x))/x}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \caption{Plot of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Does anyone have any ideas of how to 'fix' this?

Comment: Thanks for the MWE but please explain what is going wrong. Like this, everybody has to compile your code in order to see the result (screen shot appreciated) and seeing it, we have to guess, what the problem is. I do not know by head what `\frac{\sin x}{x}` should be looking like. If this is even the problem.

Comment: Off-topic: Maybe you want to use `scale only axis, width=.5\linewidth-\widthof{$-$}` as `axis` option instead of the `resizebox`.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Or package `tikzscale` is an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default number of samples is too small (25), increasing it helps to smooth the function. Also an odd number triggers the problematic value sin(0)/0, thus the number should be even for the symmetric domain.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\begin{axis}[
  grid=both,
  xmin=-4,
  xmax=4,
  ymin=-2,
  ymax=2,
  xlabel=$x$,
  ylabel=$y$,
  axis lines=center,
  >=stealth
]
  \addplot[
    domain=-4:4,
    blue,
    ultra thick,
    samples=100,
  ] plot[smooth] {sin(deg(x))/x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Plot of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]